# How to set template path within php include for wordpress API

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have the following to fill out, but for the life of me I can't get this to read the `get_template_directory_uri();` in order for the file to be properly included. This results in the page loading up to the running of this script, but then breaks everything afterwards (white space).

I've included the loop end/restart points in case this is a  wordpress issue.

```
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            </div>
    </div>


<div id="firstpost" class="topfirstpost">

    <?php
    include ( get_template_directory_uri().'/lib/forecast.io.php');

    $api_key = '<tempkey>';

    $latitude = '49.261226';
    $longitude = '-123.113927';


    $forecast = new ForecastIO($api_key);


    /*
     * GET CURRENT CONDITIONS
     */
    $condition = $forecast->getCurrentConditions($latitude, $longitude);

    echo $condition->getTemperature();

    ?>  

</div>

<div id="secondpost" class="topsecondpost">

<?php
                $first_query = new WP_Query('cat=2&showposts=1&offset=2');
                while($first_query->have_posts()) : $first_query->the_post();
            ?>
```

This is a snippet for the forecast.io api if anyone's wondering.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding a / ?

```
include( get_template_directory_uri().'/lib/forecast.io.php');
```

Comment: Yep I've tried that. Still results in everything thereafter going black.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be that get_template_directory_uri() returns an http direction, and some versions of php do not support remote file access, I would try using it only like this

```
include('lib/forecast.io.php');
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either, so I'm left to believe this web API is fracking broken... Thanks anyway. Will update this question if more answers prove fruitful.